# Yii - modify response data

Tags: html, yii, response, meta-tags

I need to dynamically generate title and meta tags in my application. So I need to get response object (f.e. like in symfony framework) and set corresponding data in  section. How can I do this in Yii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify page title, set CController::pageTitle either in your action or your view.

```
$this->pageTitle = '...';
```

As long as your main layout echoes this inbetween title tags, it works very well. (This is done by default.)

To add other headers, use

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerMetaTag($content, $name, $httpEquiv, $options);
```

Please [refer to the API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CClientScript#registerMetaTag-detail) for explanation of this signature.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is a long overdue question but for the sake of future visitors, there's a nice wiki article on exactly this:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/54/simplified-meta-tags/